# Inequality between $\lambda_2(L)$ and $\nabla J$ where $J = x^TLx$, $L$ graph Laplacian matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, normed-spaces

Let $L_1(\mathcal{G_1})$ and $L_2(\mathcal{G_2})$ be two graph Laplacian matrices corresponding to two **connected** graphs $\mathcal{G_1}$ and $\mathcal{G_2}$.

1. Suppose $\lambda_2(L_1)\geq \lambda_2(L_2)$
2. $\mathcal{G}_2\subset \mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ is connected. So you can imagine that $\mathcal{G}_2$ is a connected subgraph of $\mathcal{G}_1$.
3. Construct two potential functions $J_1=x^TL_1x$ and $J_2=x^TL_2x$.

Does the above imply $$\|\nabla J_1\| \geq \|\nabla J_2\|?$$

---

The way I am thinking is

$$\lambda_2(L_1)\geq \lambda_2(L_2) \, \Rightarrow \min_{\|x\|=1} x^TL_1x \geq \min_{\|x\|=1} x^TL_2 x $$

But I am not sure if the inequality still holds after taking gradient.

Thanks!

Comment: $\|\nabla J_1\|$ and $\|\nabla J_2\|$ aren't constant, because $J_1$ and $J_2$ aren't linear. Where are you taking the gradient?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think it is for every point.

Comment: At every point for each of them? They might not have the same dimension, unless that's an additional constraint you haven't mentioned.